# Upload file to AWS EC2 Server from AWS IoT device using AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-iot

What I intend to do:

I am receiving a file from a device connected to AWS IoT and I would like to send that file to AWS EC2 server using a AWS Lambda function. Lambda function is like the middle man which passes the file.

My questions is:

The rule in AWS IoT says "Insert this message into a code function and execute it (Lambda)". When I select this, will this send the file to Lambda sent by the device to IoT or am I supposed to write a function in lambda to subscribe to the device.

My question in brief is when I create a rule in IoT and choose an action as Lambda, what happens then? Does it forward the file to lambda? If yes then how do I receive it from the lambda function? It would be great if I could get some example function for it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an IoT rule choosing lambda. The lambda you chose will receive the message sent to IoT in the event.

You may want to take a look at [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-a-serverless-aws-iot-backend-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-dynamodb/), where IoT triggers a lambda to update a DynamoDB table (change Dynamo for your EC2).